# Eclipse java Code Completion List navigation

Tags: java, eclipse

Is anyone know how to navigate in eclipse code auto complete list without use arrow keys?
In Xcode, it can move down or up by use Ctrl + N or Ctrl + P like emacs.
And in MonoDevelop, it makes it really easy to search the code completion list. The tips you can see from this website:

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/02/07/completion_list_filtering

So how to do it in eclipse? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality described in the link is already present in eclipse. Just type your content and do `ctrl+shift` and you will get the closest options.

If you dont want to use navigation keys, just keep on typing(case insensitive)  it will filter it according to the entered content.

Also, to view Key Assist do `ctrl+shift+L`